# Cast and Convert functions are not supported on converting the column to date time format (in vbscript - Excel adodb)

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, vbscript, adodb

I have written a vbscript to connect the excel file (.xlsx) as a database using ADODB connection. I want to extract the records from excel file which has the values in 'StartDate' column greater than '15/05/2015', but on executing a adodb query an error is thrown as "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

I tried to convert the 'StartDate' column as date format using 'Convert' and 'Cast' functions, but it is not supported. How to write a query to retrieve the records?

The values in 'StartDate' column in excel looks like **"21/05/2015 0:00"** and on double clicking the field it looks like **"21/05/2015  12:00:00 AM"**

The queries I had tried (Data Mismatch error is thrown for all the queries):

```
Select * from [Student$] where StartDate >= '15/05/2015' 
Select * from [Student$] where StartDate >= '15/05/2015  12:00:00 AM'
Select * from [Student$] where StartDate >= '15/05/2015  00:00:00.000'
Select * from [Student$] where StartDate >= '15/05/2015  0:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker for [date literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is `#`, so use

```
Select * from [Student$] where StartDate >= #15/5/2015#
```

cf. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627355%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Access2007BuildingSQLStatements_UsingDateTimeCriteria)